# Chinese chill, folky music?

Tags: songs

I want to listen to more Chinese music to improve my Chinese. I like chill folk type music, and I'm having trouble finding it in Chinese. [Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzwBGHpQqhw&ab_channel=DennyLi). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on topic. You'd probably dig **My Little Airport** but I don't remember if they do much Mandarin. Milk@Coffee 牛奶咖啡, used to be another group that was more accessible in the West, but it's more pianoy kind of stuff - it's actually more like CPOP listening back to it now.

Comment: I believe this would [count as off-topic](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/faq-what-is-on-topic-and-off-topic-on-this-site), falling under "culture". Try [Chinese Forums music subforum](https://www.chinese-forums.com/forums/forum/10-music/). Also check out 朴树、李志、宋冬野、马頔、万能青年旅店 to start you off 

Answer (score 2):

For contemporary folkies, perhaps try Song Dongye 宋冬野。